# file_get_contents URL returns nothing

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I am trying to get site content(JSON reply) with file_get_contents. But it returns blank var. Trying to communicate with google's recaptcha api. When I enter URL by myself, it returns JSON message fine, but file_get_contents returns nothing.. No code, because nothing complex, just file_get_contents("http**s**://....")
openssl is enabled and allow_url_fopen is enabled too by default.

Code added:

```
$response = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$this->settings->captcha_secret_code."&response=".$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$response = json_decode($response, true);
```

$response returns 1, and if we comment out json_decoding, $response = ""

Comment: You need to share the code. Doesn't matter if it's "nothing complicated". If not, your guess is as good as ours. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, have you checked the servers error log to see if there's something in there that can help you?

Comment: Code added. But it might not help... Logs? Not yet.

Comment: Step one, create the URL in a variable, dump that variable and check that the URL is correct.

Comment: It is. I told, that if I dump it and paste into address bar, it returns expected result.

Comment: please provide the output of `var_dump([$response, $http_response_header, error_get_last()]);`

Comment: Looking at the docs, it should be a POST and not a GET request: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify (METHOD: POST). Try using cURL and make a real POST request and try

Comment: @MagnusEriksson even if the method is wrong it would return something in response, e.g. something like `{
  "success": false,
  "error-codes": [
    "invalid-input-response",
    "invalid-input-secret"
  ]
}`

Comment: Google docs says to use file_get_contents(API_URL) to get json message. And then to decode it..

Comment: @AndrewGG this makes no sense whatsoever. If the $response was really "" then json_decoding it would result in a null and not in 1. Likewise, when I fetch that url, I do get a json response. So whatever you are doing there, it's not that code you show.

Comment: I know my code pretty good and I showed a real problem and code, that references to it. Many people says, that file_get_contents does not work with https. And the workout is to install openssl and allow one directive. Nothing helps...

Answer (score 0):

Try to add context with ssl info:

```
<?php
$url = 'your_url.php';    
$opts = array(
    "ssl"=>array(
        "verify_peer"=>false,
        "verify_peer_name"=>false,
    ),
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

$result = file_get_contents( $url , NULL, $context );
echo $result;

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

For some reasons file_get_contents doesn't work with https URL's. Instead you can use cURL:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "YOUR_URL");
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$response = json_decode($response, true);
```

More complex, but it works :)